# Batch or Bulk insert records to Salesforce from C#

Tags: c#, .net, salesforce, bulkinsert, bulk

I am working on a C# application to insert multiple records into a Salesforce Object. And I'd like to insert those records as batch/bulk or in other words, if there are 5 records being inserted, I want the 'CreatedDate' to have the same created date Timestamp.

I am currently running a loop for inserting multiple records in Salesforce using the CreateAsync() method, but the CreatedDate timestamp is different for each of the  records - about 5 seconds difference.

I want the 'CreatedDate' timestamp to be the same when inserting multiple records. Please let me know a better way to achieve this.

Thank you.

Comment: Why dont you set Datetime outside the loop and call each time. So that all records has same datetimestamp

Comment: Thank you Mdyahiya for your reply. The column is the 'CreatedDate' of a record in Salesforce. I believe the value in the 'CreateDate' column is added automatically by the system as soon as a record in created. Could this even be changed?

Comment: Sorry I have no idea. Why dont you try here [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/)